# Starting from two lists, how to put the elements of the same index from each list into a list of tuples

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

Consider two lists, each with 10 elements:

```
list_one = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

list_two = ['ok', 'good', None, 'great', None, None, 'amazing', 'terrible', 'not bad', None]
```

How can I create a list of tuples in which each tuple in the list contains two elements of the same index from each list -- but also, I need to skip the None values, so my final list of 6 tuples which should look like this:

```
final_list_of_tuples = [('a', 'ok'), ('b', 'good'), ('d', 'great'), ('g', 'amazing'), ('h', 'terrible'), ('i', 'not bad')]
```

I tried the following code, but it puts every single one of the strings from list_one into a tuple with all of the strings from list_two:

```
final_list_of_tuples = []
for x in list_one:
    for y in list_two:
        if y == None:
            pass
        else:
            e = (x,y)
            final_list_of_tuples.append(e)
```

Comment: You mean: `print(list(zip(list_one, list_two)))` ?

Comment: No - this doesn't get ignore my None values.

Comment: In that case: `list(filter(lambda x: x[1], zip(list_one, list_two)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This skips pairs where the corresponding item in the second list is `None`:

```
final_list_of_tuples = [(a, b) for (a, b) in zip(list_one, list_two) if b is not None]
```

And here's one possible `for` loop version:

```
final_list_of_tuples = []
for i, b in enumerate(list_two):
    if b is not None:
        a = list_one[i]
        final_list_of_items.append((a, b))
```

Comment: I like this second solution, mostly because it stays closest to what I was attempting. I have not yet absorbed how the zip function works so I'll stick with what I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) to create the list of tuples and then remove the entries with None in it using a list comprehension.

```
[w for w in zip(list_one, list_two) if None not in w]
```

Outputs:

```
[('a', 'ok'), ('b', 'good'), ('d', 'great'), ('g', 'amazing'), ('h', 'terrible'), ('i', 'not bad')]
```

Comment: I was typing my answer as yours popped and stopped =) Decided to post it once you've deleted yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> filter(all, zip(list_one, list_two))
[('a', 'ok'), ('b', 'good'), ('d', 'great'), ('g', 'amazing'), ('h', 'terrible'), ('i', 'not bad')]
```

Comment: My favorite answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by scrolling through the indices of the two lists because they are the same size, try this...

```
for x in range(len(list_two)):
    if list_two[x] == None:
        pass
    else:
        e = (list_two[x],list_one[x])
        final_list_of_tuples.append(e)               
print(final_list_of_tuples)
```